# Help obtaining the variance of a signal from a power spectrum?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I have been reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.01831). The paper presents a power spectrum (attached). The power spectrum shows the power spectrum of velocity perturbations, $v$, in the solar atmosphere. If I want to obtain the average velocity, $\langle v\rangle^2$, do I integrate the power spectrum over frequency space? I tried this but the value I obtained seemed  far too small $\sim 10^{-5}\,\text{km}^2\,\text{s}^{-2}$. We can see that the integral is less than $0.1\times0.01=10^{-3}\,\text{km}^2\,\text{s}^{-2}$ by looking at the x and y range in the graph below. The paper suggests they observed an amplitude of the order $1\,\text{km}\,\text{s}^{-1}$. Which means integrating over frequency space gives a value which is far too small. Additionally such an integral will give dimensions of $\text{km}^2\,\text{s}^{-3}$ which is not the same dimensions as $\langle v\rangle^2$. Does anyone know what I should do to obtain $\langle v\rangle$ from the power spectrum below? I would like to get an understanding of what the y-axis means in this graph and hopefully figure out how to use this graph to obtain $\langle\dot{v}\rangle$.

[image: Power spectrum.]

Comment: The average speed will be the square root of (Pmax-Pmin)/2.

Comment: So is $P_{max}$ the power at $f=f_{min}$ where $f$ is frequency, in this case? If so, I am not sure that makes sense. What would $\langle v \rangle$ be if the power spectrum was flat? Surely your formula would give 0 as $P_{max}=P_{min}$ in that case?

Comment: Sorry, it should have been the average power, (Pmax+Pmin)/2

Comment: Thank you. Do you think think $\langle \dot{v} \rangle$ could be given by $(f_{max}^2P_{max}+f_{min}^2P_{min})/2$?